# Add link to text in neos beta 1.0.2

Tags: neoscms

I am new to Typo3 neos.
I am using neos with version 1.0.2

When i try to add links to custom content types the link will not be proper
and it appears some thing like below.For external urls it works fine.
node://06fbba05-82f1-e0b4-0e5e-4549e7aa4d11

How can i add target blank for external urls and mailto link for emails?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply a converter to your text that changes the internal presentation of the link to the real link. Examples are in:
Packages/Application/TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes/Resources/Private/TypoScript/Root.ts2

Basically if your custom node type has a property "text", you do:

```
text.@process.convertUris = TYPO3.Neos:ConvertUris
```

in your TypoScript prototype.

I think mailto: should work by typing mailto:foo@bar.com into the link box. Setting different targets is currently not supported out of the box, but could be done with a custom processor.

Comment: I wanted to link text with image (popup image).
How could i do this ?

Comment: Could you please give more info regarding how to write custom processor for adding  target as blank?