# How to convert nodes to uris in TYPO3 Neos

Tags: typo3, neoscms

I created a custom node type with a link field in TYPO3 Neos 1.2.1. When I pass the property value to the template, and try to render it as a link, then an execption is thrown:

```
Paths must not contain two consecutive slashes.
```

The link property value is »node://c969f0d4-2e01-87b9-25a8-6079c5a292fe«. [I have read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284380/add-link-to-text-in-neos-beta-1-0-2), that the link has to be converted to an URI first. However, the suggested processor has no effect on my site.

*TypoScript2*

```
prototype(Acme.MySitePackage:Teaser) < prototype(TYPO3.Neos:Content) {
    templatePath = 'resource://Acme.MySitePackage/Private/Templates/NodeTypes/Teaser.html'

    title = ${q(node).property('title')}
    text = ${q(node).property('text')}
    image = ${q(node).property('image')}
    link = ${q(node).property('link')}
    link.@process.convertUris = TYPO3.Neos:ConvertUris {
        #forceConversion = true
    }
}
```

*Fluid Template*

```
<f:debug>{link}</f:debug>
<neos:link.node node="{link}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet if you keep the processor and remove the neos:link.node from your template then the

```
<f:debug>{link}</f:debug>
```

will show a http:// link to the node.
The error happens with the link ViewHelper which expects a node or node path but neither a node:// not a href:// link (maybe we should support that in the future). So you can use a plain `<a href="{link}">`